# the extension $E=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $ \ p-1 \ $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $\zeta \neq 1$ be a root of the equation $x^p-1$. Prove that $ \operatorname{irr}(\zeta, \mathbb{Q})=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{p-1}$  and then conclude that that the extension $ \ E=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta) \ $ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $p-1$.

**Answer:**

Let $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{p-2}+x^{p-1}$

We will use Einstein's criterion to show that this is irreducible.

Look at ,

$$f(x+1)=1+(x+1)+(x+1)^2+\cdots+(x+1)^{p-2}+(x+1)^{p-1} \  \\ \Rightarrow f(x+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} y^{k-j} $$

Now foreach $0 \leq n \leq p-1$, the coefficient on $y^n$ is

$$ \sum_{k=n}^{p-1} \binom{k}{k-n} =\sum_{k=n}^{p-1} \binom{k}{n} =\binom{p}{n+1}$$

Thus we see that

$ f(x+1)=x^{p-1}+px^{p-2}+\cdots+ \frac{p(p-1)}{2} x+p \ $ , which is a monic polynomial.

Clearly this polynomial staisfies Einstein's criterion of irreducibility .

Thus $f(x+1)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

This implies $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

So $\operatorname{irr}(\zeta , \mathbb{Q} )= 1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{p-1}$

**But I do not use the condition** $\zeta \neq 1$.

**Am I right ?**

What about the next part?

Comment: What's the factorisation of $x^p-1$?

Comment: You used it when you said that $\zeta$ was a root of $f(x)$, since $x=1$ is not a root of $f$. $f(1)=p\neq0$.

Comment: Now try the same problem but for $\mathbb{Z}_p(\zeta)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: I'm sure both Einstein and Eisenstein are rolling over in their graves.  The guy who invented the result you use is the latter of the two; credit where credit is due.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis [Indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) "Eisentstein".

Comment: @totoro:  thank you, thank you.  Corrected.

Comment: given that $ \zeta \neq 1 \ $ is a root of $ \ x^p-1 \ $

Comment: You did it yourself. If $\zeta\neq1$ is a root of $x^p-1=(x-1)f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is the polynomial $f$ that you defined, then $\zeta$ is a root of $f(x)$.

Comment: what about the next part? I mean how to show that  $ \ \mathbb{Q} (\zeta) \ $ is an algebraic extension of $ \mathbb{Q} \ $ of degree $ p-1 \ $ ?

Comment: Any element $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)=\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]/(f(\zeta))$ gives a remainder of degree $<p-1$ after division by $f(\zeta)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]$. Therefore, $1,\zeta, \zeta^2,...,z^{p-2}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]/(f(\zeta))$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. This basis has $p-1$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$ is not a root of $1+x+..+x^{p-1}$ but so is $\zeta$.

Comment: given that $ \ \zeta \neq 1 \ $ is a root of $ \ x^p-1 \ $.p=odd prime

Comment: Is my proof is correct ? If correct then how to do the next part in the question?

Comment: yes, i think so